# Any elegant way to generate numeric value of the same type based on input numeric type?

Tags: java

I have a function which takes as input a numeric value (`Long`/`Integer`/`Byte`/`Double`/`BigDouble` ...) and set the output value to `1` if it's larger than some threshold value, otherwise `0`. The function may look like this,

```java
static Number foo(Number input) {
    if (input > threshold) { return 1;}
    else { return 0;}
}
```

But I've to keep the output the same type as input. One thing I can do is to enumerate all `Number` types and do casts and repeat the same logic like:

```java
static Number foo(Number input) {
    if (input instanceof Double) {
        if (input > threshold) { return new Double(1.0);}
        else { return new Double(0);}
    } else if (input instanceof Integer) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

So, I don't know if there's some more simple and elegant way to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Overload the method with the four primitive number types. Alternatively, make the method accept a `double` as parameter and let it return an `int`. Every primitive number type can be automatically converted to `double`. Or a mix of both solutions. --- Since you have a working solution and as for "elegance" (i.e. a code review), the question may be better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Is this valid `input > threshold`, it won't compile as the the operator `>` cannot be applied to a `Number`?

Comment: I am also wondering why this method doesn't return boolean? And you see: 0 and 1 are int literals. Why bother turning them in anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Well... since comments are limited in length, I decided to formulate my comment as an answer.

I inferred from your question that the `Atomic...` classes are not relevant. I further assume that the six primitive number types (`byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float` and `double`) are the ones of interest. We can use a combination of overloading and clever use of automatic type widening:

```
public static final double THRESHOLD = ...;

public static byte foo(final byte input) {
    return internalFoo(input);
}

public static short foo(final short input) {
    return internalFoo(input);
}

public static int foo(final int input) {
    return internalFoo(input);
}

public static long foo(final long input) {
    return internalFoo(input);
}

public static float foo(final float input) {
    return internalFoo((double) input);
}

public static double foo(final double input) {
    return internalFoo(input);
}

private static byte internalFoo(final double input) {
    return (byte) (input > TRESHOLD ? 1 : 0);
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/ntnoIl)

This works since every primitive number type can be automatically widened to be `double`. Following this argumentation, one could also do away with all the overloads an just use `internalFoo`:

```
public static byte foo(final double input) {
    return (byte) (input > THRESHOLD ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: So apparently, the answer is no.  (i.e. in terms of elegance).

Comment: Depends on your definition of elegance =)

Comment: So I still have to keep the `instanceof` conditions, since the input type is `Number`.

Comment: If you have to work with `Number` then yes, you have to check the type since there are subclasses (e.g. `AtomicInteger`, `AtomicLong`,...) that are not autoboxed